# Reasons for sporadic bluetooth disconnect on iPhone

Tags: iphone, bluetooth

my system consists of a bluetooth accessory and an iPhone. Sometimes I see a link loss between the two devices in idle mode. I have only seen it in idle (sniff) mode so far. Sometimes it happens every few minutes, sometimes after an hour or so. I have no clue why. My accessory does a reconnect right after loosing the connection, but that is very bad user experience.

What I did so far:
I read the iPhone accessory guide and was a bit surprised about the advice to set the sniff period to 15 ms. In the example application of my chipset (CSR) I see a period of 800 slots == 500 ms. I configured my application to use minimum of 15 ms. Nevertheless the iPhone indicated a period of 384 slots.

I also checked the supervision timeout. It is set to 8000 slots == 5 seconds. Seems ok.

I also have the impression that it mainly happens if two phones are connected to the accessory. The second phone is an android. The android phone does not have a problem.

Now I run out of ideas what to do. Do you have a idea here?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of sniffing and debugging I found out the reason on physical layer. The situation was the following: I have a headset (HS), an iPhone (I) and an Android (A).
To reproduce I had to:

1. Connect HS and iPhone
2. Connect HS and Android. Important: The Android device had to initiate the connection.

Now the HS is in the situation where both peer devices are in bluetooth master role, the HS is in slave role on both connections.

What now happens is that both master may set the HS into sniff mode with some sniff interval which is conflicting with each other. Due to time slot collisions the connections is then lost.

One possible solution is to detect this situation on the HS and either never go to sniff mode or use a shorter timeout to change from active to sniff mode. In this case, the HS can propose the sniff intervals for both connections and prevent conflicts.